# jQuery UI .draggable()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

good day!

Just have a question if any of you came across my issue.
Issue is that I want to make the dynamically created div elements to be draggable. Yes, can achieve it by `$('.frameHolder').draggable()`. But the problem is when the divs are up to a thousand it causes the browser to get really slow (like 800ms - measured by performance.now()).

Here's the snippet:

```
var frames = [];

for (var i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
  frames.push('<div id="frame' + i + '" class="frame"><div id="frameHolder' + i + '" class="frameHolder"></div></div>');
}

$('.frameHolder').draggable({
  containment: $('#layerFrameContainer .layerFrame),
  axis: 'x',
  cursor: 'pointer',
  helper: 'clone',
  grid: [10, 10]
});
```

Thanks guys!

Comment: The easiest solution to this is to not put 1000 divs in the page. Use pagination if possible. If that's not possible then your only option is to optimise the JS code. For which I'd suggest not using jQuery at all.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Pagination is not possible for this. oh man, well I need to find other way then. Thanks man!

Comment: Do all `div`s need to be draggable at all times? Maybe just make 1 specific element draggable at a time, like when it has focus. What is the end goal here, it's a bit vague what you're trying to do.

Comment: The issue, as I see it, is that you create around 1000 jQuery Objects, and this begins to consume more of the browsers memory. I bet you can watch it grow. It may be only 800 ms delay on your system, but try a system with less memory or using an older CPU. I bet you will see the browser stop responding all together. As @RoryMcCrossan points out, you'd need to optimize your code such that it uses less memory and resources. This can be done with raw code or reducing the libraries included.

Comment: Or... maybe Sortable is more what you need. Again, not enough context to your post to understand what you need.

Comment: I do not see a delay of 800 ms when I load 1000 elements: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/mpns7w3n/1/

Comment: Getting 538 ms: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/mpns7w3n/2/

Comment: Switching to `.each()` degraded to 646 ms: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/mpns7w3n/5/

Comment: Shaved off 10 to 30 ms by running it inline, seeing 506 ~ 508 ms: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/mpns7w3n/8/

Comment: @Twisty Yeah should be draggable at all times. Will definitely look into your suggestion (1 element draggable on demand), never thought of that. Thanks guys! Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another way to make a large number of elements draggable, without a larger load time upfront, is to do it on demand. Instead of making all of the elements draggable just make those that need to be draggable as they are needed. From my comments, I tested a number of methods to decrease the load time and got down to ~500 ms.

Consider the following: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/mpns7w3n/11/

**HTML**

```
<div id="layerFrameContainer">
  <div class="layerFrame">
  </div>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(function() {
  var frames = [];

  function dragInit(t) {
    if (t.hasClass("ui-draggable")) {
      return;
    }
    console.log("Making frame[" + t.parent().index() + "] > frameHolder draggable");
    t.draggable({
      containment: $('#layerFrameContainer .layerFrame'),
      axis: 'x',
      cursor: 'pointer',
      helper: 'clone',
      grid: [10, 10]
    });
  }

  var t0 = performance.now();
  for (var i = 1; i <= 1000; i++) {
    var frame = $("<div>", {
      id: "frame-" + i
    });
    var frameHolder = $("<div>", {
      id: "frameHolder-" + i,
      class: "frameHolder"
    }).appendTo(frame);
    frames.push(frame);
    $(".layerFrame").append(frame);
  }
  var t1 = performance.now();
  console.log("Call to loop took " + (t1 - t0) + " milliseconds.");
  $(".layerFrame").on("mouseover", ".frameHolder", function(e) {
    dragInit($(this));
  });
  var t2 = performance.now();
  console.log("Call to assign draggable took " + (t2 - t1) + " milliseconds.");
});
```

The initial load time will be under 200 ms.

As the user moves the mouse across the page, the user must `mouseover` before they can `click` an element. We can use this to trigger `.draggable()` for that target. It is then draggable when the user clicks on the element.

Even if the user does not click, the element is now draggable. As the user cannot click an element before he mouses over it, no element will ever be un-draggable. Faster loading and same user experience.

Comment: Man, you're definitely a savior! Can't thank you enough. Just made the elements to be draggable and droppable on demand and no more memory issues. This solution is something I must definitely drill on my brain.